# Spring Security - Get username in AuthenticationSuccessHandler without UserDetails/UserDetailsService

Tags: authentication, spring-security

I'm trying to set the LastLogin time for a user in a custom AuthenticationSuccessHandler, however I don't know of a way of retrieving the username (since all the authority functions seem to return null because I'm not working with UserDetails).
The user data is stored in a MYSQL table and I'm using Hibernate to retrieve/create/update users. Within my application I'm using a self-written User class that doesn't have anything to do with the Spring User class. I don't have any custom UserDetails/UserDetailsService and I would like to avoid them, since I cannot change the DB table layout (as in add additional values)

The AuthenticationSuccessHandler looks like this:

```
public class PostSuccessfulAuthenticationHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {
@Autowired
private UserService userService;
@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        Authentication authentication) throws ServletException, IOException 
        {
            userService.trackUserLogin(authentication.getName()); //Doesn't work, getName seems to return null
            super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
        }
}
```

My applicationContext-security.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">

<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>
<!-- authentication-success-handler-ref='authSuccHandler' -->
<http use-expressions="true" disable-url-rewriting="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="..." access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <form-login login-page="/index.htm"
                authentication-failure-handler-ref='authFailureHandler'
                authentication-success-handler-ref='authSuccHandler'
                default-target-url='...'
                always-use-default-target='true'/>
    <logout logout-success-url="..."/>
    <session-management invalid-session-url="/index.htm">
        <concurrency-control max-sessions="2" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" />
    </session-management>
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="mysqldataSource" 
                    authorities-by-username-query="select username, authority from benutzer where username = ?"
                    users-by-username-query="select username, password, enabled from benutzer where username = ?"/>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

The login itself works fine (even if I just comment out the trackUserLogin line in my AuthenticationSuccessHandler) which leads me to believe that there has to be a way to get that username. Can anyone help?

Comment: The description of your setup doesn't seem to match the configuration. For example, you say you are using Hibernate to retrieve users, but the configuration is using `jdbc-user-service`, for authentication and this **is** a `UserDetailsService`, so you are working with `UserDetails`. It's not clear what you mean by "all the authority functions seem to return null". You also say that the `getName()` method "seems to return null", which it can't actually do. You should probably debug the code and verify what's happening. You might also look at using an `ApplicationListener` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `authentication.getPrincipal()`.